# A Space with scalar matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate the following quotient vector space $\mathbb{M_3(R)}/S$ Where $S$ is the subspace of the scalar matrices of order 3. $S$ it is precisely the set of diagonal matrices that right on the main diagonal all the elements are equal.

My work:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices such that $A,B∈M_3(R)$, We say that $A∼B$ iff $A−B∈S$. But I do not know how to continue, that is, I do not know how to make this happen. I need to find the equivalence class of a matrix $A∈M_3(R)$. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: What would a reasonable answer be? The quotient space is...well...the quotient space. Are you looking for the dimension? A basis? A name?

Comment: Can you help me find the equivalence class of a matrix $A$, of order 3x3 in this quotient space?

Comment: I assume $\Bbb M_3(\Bbb R)$ is the field of reals over the general linear group... correct? Otherwise, we can't apply "subtraction" (multiplication by inverse) of matrices.

Comment: @ZachHauk $\Bbb M_3(\Bbb R)$ means that it is the vector space of all square matrices of order 3. Can you help me, please?

Comment: $\;\Bbb M_3(\Bbb R)\;$ is **the ring** (or linear space) of all square matrices over the reals. Not a field.

Comment: @ZachHauk matrix multiplication has nothing to do with this exercise

Comment: @DonAntonio So, addition is defined componentwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that the equivalence class of the matrix $A$ is the set of all $B \in \Bbb M_3(\Bbb R)$ such that $A - B \in S$; that is, there exists some scalar matrix $M$ of the form $\lambda \;\mathrm{Id}$ for $\lambda \in \Bbb R - \{0\}$ such that $A - B = M$ Thus, we have that

$$A = M + B$$
and hence
$$B = A- M$$

So what does this tell us? The equivalence class of $A$ is the set of all $A-M$ for $M \in S$.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalence class of a matrix $\;A=(a_{ij})\;$ is the set of all matrices $\;B\;$ such that $\;A-B\in S\;$ , and this means

$$B=(b_{ij})\in[A]\iff a_{ij}=b_{ij}\;,\;\;\forall\;i\neq j\;,\;\;1\leq i,\,j\le3$$

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but for example, to better understand this concept, since I am a beginner ... what would be the equivalence class of the following matrix $A= \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 4 & 3 \\
      1 & -2 & 0 \\
      5 & -8 & 3  \end{array}\right).$?

Comment: @Daniela: all the matrices with $\;4\;$ in the entry $\;1-2\;$ and 3 in $\;1-3\;$ and $\;1\;$ in $\;2-1\;$ ...etc . This means: all the matrices which are entrywise **identical** to that matrix *except* for the elements on the main diagonal. It think that's clear from the answer above...\

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer of the form that many people might want; I personally don't like it much, but I'm not the decider.

The elements of the quotient are, as DonAntonio points out, sets of matrices. But we can pick, in each set, one special matrix, and use that to "name" the set. If I can then tell you for any matrix $A$ what is the "special" matrix associated to $A$, you'll have a sense that the set of special matrices is "really" the right answer. Here goes:

Let a matrix $A$ have entries $a_{ij}$. Then define
$$
p: M_{33}(\Bbb R) \to M_{33}(\Bbb R): A \mapsto A - (a_{11} + a_{22} + a_{33}) I.
$$

The resulting matrix clearly differs from $A$ by a multiple of the identity. And if we say that $U$ is the image of $p$, then for $A \in U$, we have $p(A) = A$. So we can say that $p$ is a kind of "projection" onto $U$.

Furthermore, it turns out to be true (by direct computation) that 
$$
P(cI) = 0\\
p(A + B) = p(A) + p(B) \\
p(cA) = c p(A)
$$
for $c \in \Bbb R$ and any $A,B$. Hence (1) U is a subspace, and (2)p is a linear transformation from $M_{33}$ to $U$. Furthermore, there's a 1-1 correspondence between $\mathbb{M_3(R)}/S$ and $U$, given by $[A] \mapsto p(A)$. (The statements above show that this does not depend on the representative we choose in the class of $A$). The inverse of the map is simply 
$$
K \in U \mapsto [K] \in \mathbb{M_3(R)}/S = \{K + Q \mid Q \in S \}.
$$

So it's very reasonable to say that $U$ "really really looks like" the quotient space, since we have a bijective linear correspondence between the two.